# How to retrieve transaction data from PayPal (Smart buttons) using Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, paypal, codeigniter-3

I am trying to implement PayPal Smart buttons, I can make the payment using Sandbox accounts and I get positive response that transaction completed, but after that PayPal provided PHP code for retrieving transaction details. I do have a problem with understanding the code and also how to use it. I guess this is the last part then I can insert details to my db. Please help me on that.

```
<?php

 namespace Sample;

  require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
 //1. Import the PayPal SDK client that was created in `Set up Server-Side SDK`.
 use Sample\PayPalClient;
 use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersGetRequest;

 class GetOrder
 {

    // 2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
 /**
  *You can use this function to retrieve an order by passing order ID as an argument.
  */
  public static function getOrder($orderId)
{

// 3. Call PayPal to get the transaction details
$client = PayPalClient::client();
$response = $client->execute(new OrdersGetRequest($orderId));
/**
 *Enable the following line to print complete response as JSON.
 */
//print json_encode($response->result);
print "Status Code: {$response->statusCode}\n";
print "Status: {$response->result->status}\n";
print "Order ID: {$response->result->id}\n";
print "Intent: {$response->result->intent}\n";
print "Links:\n";
foreach($response->result->links as $link)
{
  print "\t{$link->rel}: {$link->href}\tCall Type: {$link->method}\n";
}
   // 4. Save the transaction in your database. Implement logic to save transaction to your database 
for future reference.
print "Gross Amount: {$response->result->purchase_units[0]->amount->currency_code} {$response->result->purchase_units[0]->amount->value}\n";

// To print the whole response body, uncomment the following line
// echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
 }
 }

   /**
  *This driver function invokes the getOrder function to retrieve
    *sample order details.
    *
   *To get the correct order ID, this sample uses createOrder to create a new order
   *and then uses the newly-created order ID with GetOrder.
 */
 if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
 {
   GetOrder::getOrder('REPLACE-WITH-ORDER-ID', true);
  }
  ?>
```